# How to get server side variable value in xsl template?

Tags: asp.net, xslt

I want use localized strings from resources in xsl template as in aspx page, like this:
`<%=GetLocalizedString("grid_numberof_claim")%>`. I am trying use

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
    <![CDATA[<%=GetLocalizedString("grid_numberof_claim")%>]]>
</xsl:text>
```

but it is not useful.

Actually i can pass localized strings inside XML node, for example "localization". But i am looking for way to get its value in aspx style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ASPX style isn't possible.

You can use `XsltArgumentList` to send parameters to your XSLT template, as explained here: [HOW TO: Execute Parameterized XSL Transformations in .NET Applications](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321704)

**EDIT**: Yes, you can pass arguments client-side too.

```
xmldoc = ... // your xml document

var xslt = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate.4.0");
var xslDoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.4.0");

xslDoc.async = false;
xslDoc.load("YourTemplate.xsl");
xslt.stylesheet = xslDoc;

xslProc = xslt.createProcessor();
xslProc.input = xmldoc;
xslProc.addParameter("param1", 123);
xslProc.addParameter("param2", "abc");
xslProc.transform();
```

But client-side leads to another solution: You can *rename* your XSLT file to ASPX and to use `<%= %>` syntax

Comment: Hm... not un my case. I am making xslt transformation from client side, so i can not pass XsltArgumentList.

Comment: Wery well. Thanks for answer :)